# Tridion 2011 Core Service: How can I delete previous versions of a component?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I would like to use the Core Service to delete previous versions of a component, only keeping the most recent version. How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation says about the Delete method:
"Permanently deletes the item or a specific version of the item from the system"

So you can delete versions by passing in the uri of the version (e.g. tcm:2-123-64-v4).

Answer (score 8):

Tridion ships by default with a tool called **"Purge Tool"** that you can use for this purpose.

- You can  find more info on the [online documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#url=http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com:80/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US&action=search&query=purge%2520tools&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1350285477583&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_1837C7746D9E496099784B3C4C81F310&query=&scope=&filename=PurgeTool.xml&docid=concept_1837C7746D9E496099784B3C4C81F310&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=)

There is a **visual interface**, but also if you have business requirements to do this programmatically, or as a scheduled task, it also provides a [command line interface](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#url=http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com:80/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US&action=search&query=purge%2520tools&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1350285477583&eventType=lcContent.loadDocidheading-259253576&query=&scope=&filename=AG_PurgeTool_4_concept.xml&docid=idheading-259253576&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know of the Purge Tool. Unfortunately it's not quite what I need. 

I am creating a tool which deletes the history of components classified with a specific keyword. Is it possible to accomplish this with the Purge Tool or by using the Core Service?